# Swab tests reveals I have a staph infection. Can it tell if it's MRSA? Or is that a different test? If so, can that distinguish HA-MRSA & C-MRSA?

Tags: infection, autoimmune-disease, lupus, staph-infections, mrsa

I had a blistered rash that kept spreading so my doctor took a swab to see if there was any kind of bacterial cultures present. The results came back today -- I am positive for a staph infection.

Because I have Lupus, and have had over 15 surgeries, my doctor asked me asked me if I had a history of MSRA (I suspect HA-MRSA, considering my medical history), but I had not heard of MSRA before so  I told him "no." So he prescribed me Cefalexin.

**Do the the swab tests they do to see if any bacterial cultures grow --- do they give information if the staph infection is resistant to antibiotics -- caused by MRSA? If so, would the info be detailed enough to tell whether or not if I had HA-MRSA or C-MRSA? Or would they have to do a different kind of testing for that?**

I'm assuming I'll eventually know if I have MRSA by seeing if my staph infection gets better, but I'm wondering if the tests would have had the results for that to begin with? Or if that is just determined based off of medical history and living conditions?

Comment: You might find [this question](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3268/how-does-a-mrsa-test-work?rq=1) interesting, although it does not cover all the details you asked about.